# jQuery Mobile pageinit re-binds on every page load

Tags: jquery-mobile

Adding my bindings to the pageinit event like so:

```
$('#mypage').on("pageinit", function () {

     $('#login-sumbit').on('click', function () { 
       console.log('button clicked');
     });

});
```

I would expect pageinit to bind the click event once only. But what happens in my single page app is that the button is binding every time the page is loaded even when clicking back.

This results in undesirable multiple duplicate binds. Any ideas on what event to use to bind only once in my single page app, so that loading the page again (back button, loading inline page) in the same session doesn't re-bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer myself, turns out quite rightly pageinit fires every time the page is loaded even though it's not reloading from the server, otherwise what would fire when a new page is shown.

pageinit is the right event but I need to use .one not .on, .one will bind one time only.

```
$('#mypage').on("pageinit", function () {

     $('#login-sumbit').one('click', function () { 
       console.log('button clicked');
     });

});
```

Now everything works as expected. Better still I've found you can use .one with the pageinit event for even more control over your bindings and data loads perfect for my requirements.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 $('#login-sumbit').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
     console.log('button clicked');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks I think .one() is a shortcut for that.